# Decoding the Kaadi system

Tags: code-golf, string, parsing, alphabet

You have come across an old Indian manuscript, one that describes mounds of buried treasure. The manuscript also tells you the location of the treasure, except that some crucial numbers have been encoded indirectly into the text. You figure out that the text uses a 'Kaadi' system, a restricted subset of the more common 'Katapayadi' system.

(The [Katapayadi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katapayadi_system) system is an ancient Indian system to encode numerals as letters, often used as mnemonics to remember long numbers.)

Your task here is to decode text encoded in the Kaadi system and print out the numerical value.

#### Details

**Input characters**

The Kaadi system is based on the [Katapayadi system's rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katapayadi_system#Rules_and_practices), but uses only the first row of consonants. Your text here has been transliterated to Latin alphabet, and is known to contain only:

- vowels 'a','e','i','o','u'
- consonants 'g','k','c','j', and their capital forms (to represent the [aspirated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspirated_consonant) form of those consonants), and 'ṅ' and 'ñ'.

(You may choose to receive and handle 'ṅ' as 'ng' and 'ñ' as 'ny' if that's more convenient in your language.)

**Value assignment**

In this system,

1. each consonant when followed by a vowel has a digit associated with it. These are:

   `'k'=>1, 'K'=>2,`
   `'g'=>3, 'G'=>4,`
   `'ṅ'=>5,`
   `'c'=>6, 'C'=>7,`
   `'j'=>8, 'J'=>9,`
   `'ñ'=>0`

*Note however, that these values apply only when these consonants are followed by a vowel.* `kacCi` has the same value as `kaCi` (`ka`,`Ci`=(1,7)) since the middle c is unaccompanied by a vowel.

2. Additionally, an initial vowel or sequence of two vowels represents a 0. `aikaCi` would be: `ai`,`ka`,`Ci` = (0,1,7)
3. Extra vowels anywhere else in the middle of the text have no value: `kauCia` is the same as `kaCi`, the extra vowels can be ignored.

**Final numeric value**

Once the digit values of the letters have been figured out, the final numerical value is obtained as the reverse order of those digits i.e. the first digit from the text is the least significant digit in the final value.

Eg.
`GucCi` has `Gu` and `Ci`, so (4, 7), so the final value is 74.
`kakakaGo` is (1,1,1,4), so the the answer is 4111.
`guṅKo` is (3,2), so encodes 23. (`gungKo` if using ASCII-equivalent.)

#### Input

- A string containing a Kaadi-encoded text

  - will contain only vowels and the above consonants
  - the vowels are always in lowercase and occur in groups of no more than 2
  - you may choose to accept the letters for 5 and 0 either as their Unicode characters 'ṅ' and 'ñ' or as their ASCII equivalents 'ng' and 'ny' (they're in lowercase in either form)
  - you may assume there are no spaces or punctuations

#### Output

- The numerical value of the text, as given by the above rules

  - for empty input, an empty output or any false-y output in your language of choice is acceptable, in addition to 0
  - for invalid input (input with anything other than vowels and the above consonants), the output is undefined - anything goes

#### Test cases

```
"GucCi"
=> 74
"kakakaGo"
=> 4111
"aiKaCiigukoJe"
=> 913720
""
=> 0 //OR empty/falsey output
"a"
=> 0
"ukkiKagijeCaGaacoJiiKka"
=> 1964783210
"kegJugjugKeg"
=> 2891
"guṅKo"
=> 23
"Guñaaka"
=> 104
"juñiKoṅe"
=>5208
```

(the last ones can be:

```
"gungKo"
=> 23
"Gunyaaka"
=> 104
"junyiKonge"
=>5208
```

if you prefer that.)

Standard rules for [I/O](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/73884) and [loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/73884) apply. May the best golfer win!

Comment: Can `aiaKaci` be input? (3 leading vowels)

Comment: There is also no test case which ends in a consonant; can we assume the input will always end in a vowel?

Comment: No for 3 leading vowels. In fact, I don't think it makes sense for 3 consequent vowels to occur anywhere in the input (2 English vowels are sometimes needed to represent one Sanskrit vowel sound, but never 3). Can I add that in as an input constraint now or is it too late?

Comment: Input *can* end in a consonant, I'll add a test case for that.

Comment: It's not too late to clarify that the input won't have 3 leading vowels. That won't break any submissions, and I doubt anyone have written longer code to take that into account, and if they have they can simply remove it. Nice first question by the way! :)

Comment: In case it helps in some languages: `ord(c)%47%10` gives a unique index in `[0..9]` for each consonant. (With `ord("ṅ")=7749` and `ord("ñ")=241`.)

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 83 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.replace(s=/(^|[ṅcCjJñkKgG])[aeiou]/g,(_,c)=>o=(s+s).search(c)%10+o,o='')&&o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZGxbsIwEIZ3niJCKtgiJXGIChnCkiFSMlTqimh1co3rOOUiHFdC6toHYuzMk/RJ0qQSQxO4W//vv//uCvgAww@qqu/3@CqaXdyYeG3mB1GVwAUxsUeePzc/3188KbLzSecy3dINCIV260mXvLicxmuMiZkZOjcCDvyNcHrH/Bm6GE@ndDLBhuPeYCnmJUqyI@PU8kSNKXWG5XnOMhz19Bq6TvEK0upDxlifAJVDopS0GjPxH2uJiC2Wgd9nrge6ML7z@OSI96o@ejsojTg6aOvK1oPJt206l77cat1GlaoQCaQAHDOlcv1n0spZ9BAuV4uADTgtZGZlYWUuZG9iywWraHASadsv5njz7MFiNHjT@QSgr27UhfPD5hc)

#### How?

We use the following regular expression to match either the beginning of the string or one of the Kaadi consonants, followed by a vowel:

```javascript
/(^|[ṅcCjJñkKgG])[aeiou]/g
```

For each match in the input string, we invoke the following callback function that takes the content **c** of the capturing group as parameter:

```javascript
(_, c) => o = (s + s).search(c) % 10 + o
```

We find the value of the consonant by looking for its position in the regular expression (coerced to a string by adding it to itself).

The consonants are ordered in such a way that their value is equal to their position modulo **10**:

```
string   : /  (  ^  |  [  ṅ  c  C  j  J  ñ  k  K  g  G  ]  )  [  a  e  i  o  u  ]  /  g
position : 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 ...
modulo 10: -  -  -  -  -  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3  4  -  ...
```

When we match the beginning of the string instead of a consonant, **c** is an empty string whose position in the regular expression is **0** -- which, conveniently, is the expected result in that case.

Finally, we insert this digit at the beginning of the output string **o**.

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 41 bytes

```
T`ñkKgGṅcCjJ`d`.[aeiou]
^[aeiou]
0
\D

V`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYw9CgIxEEb77x6ClegZIgwkrdj4Qz7WEGYHDIhzBA@0pfWexJPEtZDXvOa9R3nqnbu@WkvuhzxPlqp83q8hjDHf8ubEos0vuP5li/MeOObexYegMP6QBiYG1erWYgEIN9PEqmMJFHJoUTUZUX3ZpwbxeeKSfgE) Link includes test cases. Explantion:

```
T`ñkKgGṅcCjJ`d`.[aeiou]
```

Translate the consonants that are followed by vowels.

```
^[aeiou]
0
```

Handle a leading vowel.

```
\D
```

Delete everything else.

```
V`
```

Reverse the result.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 93 bytes

```python
lambda s,h=u'ñkKgGṅcCjJ'.find:''.join(`h(c)`*(0>h(v)<h(c))for c,v in zip(u'ñ'+s,s))[::-1]
```

An unnamed function accepting a Unicode string which returns a string representation of the base ten result.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5BTsMwEEXX5BSWWNgucQSsqoh0k0Wk5AiAVOM4ySTUjmK7qOw5UJesexJOEuykCI000n//68@MJ9tp9Tjfsg2TSugaVJs627CtBxEcRj1Z5LEU5k@Zk0GRX4mxtXYWZVc/aaX9mMDKiWDfsMWU/Kdo1GQv8zs/vNUcmbjLHL6ch6otfr6/RN6XOGlA1SnGSa9BkX1HBN1vyP2uI0f6FBRt9IREfESg0CeMJBTgOxMbSp/TlD28ziFgpbEh4e3CiRxwjBweeJhCL4JXPAdo3aBLuYCVLtsNA1S8hV7mvOBc6BKgGlavdf7Vau0o3OXMfSWmaXQzTqDscjhGmLGdTzQkSDr/Ag)**

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, <s>136</s> 126 bytes

```java
s->{for(int i=s.length,t;i-->0;)if("aeiou".contains(s[i]))System.out.print(i<1?0:(t="ñkKgGṅcCjJ".indexOf(s[i-1]))<0?"":t);}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##XVG9bsIwEN55CsuTIzURrATKkCESUenAiBiuxkkvDnaEbdQKMfaBGDvzJH2S1AlBLZElS3f@7vs5l3CEsNzJhldgDHkBVKcRIaisOOTABVm1JSFHjTvC2doeUBWbLTFB7Pvnkb@MBYucrIgic9KY8PmU6wPzDATnJqqEKuz7k40xDJ/HcYA5oyBQOxpxrazXM8xscBsE609jxT7Szka1V7EMZ5PFeMrsnF4vMivSn@8vnpRLGqHaiY/XvJ0LJ35yNl5QOrVBfG7i1lHt3irvqDfWWd97oT/3ENxSWWEso6njCdIu0L0loT2pfuxCBgli4aReiseXAW5QSokZFFiKBFIArpeImRyACufjZQPB1F0vAHfo/213oTrQLZT/sdrZPpaKOOvqyNQVdvZ62uGOK8V66nPzCw)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->{                           // Method with String-array parameter and String return-type
  for(int i=s.length,t;i-->0;) //  Loop backwards over the input-characters
    if("aeiou".contains(s[i])) //   If the current character is a vowel:
      System.out.print(        //    Print:
         i<1?                  //     If we're at the first character:
          0                    //      Print a 0
         :                     //     Else:
          (t="ñkKgGṅcCjJ".indexOf(s[i-1]))<0?
                               //      If the character before the vowel is also a vowel:
           ""                  //       Print nothing
          :                    //      Else:
           t);}                //       Print the correct digit of the consonant
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 101 bytes

```python
lambda s,S=u'ñkKgGṅcCjJ':''.join(`S.find(c)`for c,n in zip(u'ñ'+s,s)if c in(n in'aeiou')*S)[::-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZAxbsJAEEV7TjGCYm2CgTVWDJZI48ISLiKFMonEZO11BsOuhb0F6XMgytScJCcxuPGi6f57fzSa6tx8a@W3I/DGHuRK6IxUEYFppLfssoFcf7QHPH5lCPVkuzbseinTIvn/@xXxfsMixqZ7TcrZbaeSVOYIdyf1CcREASn4ocrpKuypntQuSRD31OkQw5y0Ye54675Hkcc/2@pEqnGkM0yMiGnoujCC9QuEwaAnJXaT6B4GnHOLMcWYqDCl3uS9suKL0J9bqQdzmM1e3yA/Vs15JvFQ52fQpqlM87DR2jY0ZUkpFrTPY0wQhd4QpaVV@eo5CJcLn9uOGRbm/rLUXu4vHmBirhfExxXzoL0B)

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>104</s> 102 bytes

```python
lambda s,S='ñkKgGṅcCjJ':''.join(str(S.find(c))for c,n in zip('ñ'+s,s)if c in(n in'aeiou')*S)[::-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZAxboNAEEV7n2LlFLubEMMCCjESaSiQoIgUyiTFZA1kwGYRsAXpcyCXqX2SnATjBtB0//3/NTPN0H@r2hnz4GM8wunrAKQz0oBezlVSRP9/vzIsY@pTuisV1qzrW5bucqwPTHKeq5ZIoyZYkx9s2BSiD53RccyJnER2IxQyVJry@5S/@/6j@BybFuue5WwbaRnilnNyR4IX4rmbmVRwm0jN0BVCLBgSCBELXak4my174Xi2tZhmYBHTfH0j2anpBzOHY5cNROm@0f2qcXEvoq4qTKDAMgshApAqRkyqxSr2T6737NhilSn09LNkWdx2Nqt7L2eAdYHljlc)

---

Saved

- -3 bytes, thanks to Rod

Comment: Well, you can if you [add the header](https://tio.run/##TZAxbsJAEEV7TjGCYm2CgTVWDJZI48ISLiKFMonEZO11BsOuhb0F6XMgytScJCcxuPGi6f57fzSa6tx8a@W3I/DGHuRK6IxUEYFppLfssoFcf7QHPH5lCPVkuzbseinTIvn/@xXxfsMixqZ7TcrZbaeSVOYIdyf1CcREASn4ocrpKuypntQuSRD31OkQw5y0Ye54675Hkcc/2@pEqnGkM0yMiGnoujCC9QuEwaAnJXaT6B4GnHOLMcWYqDCl3uS9suKL0J9bqQdzmM1e3yA/Vs15JvFQ52fQpqlM87DR2jY0ZUkpFrTPY0wQhd4QpaVV@eo5CJcLn9uOGRbm/rLUXu4vHmBirhfExxXzoL0B), but I forgot the unicode prefix in the strings, after all, it would save a single byte

Comment: @Rod, ah thanks, I'd forgotten about the unicode prefix :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 27 bytes

```
Żµe€Øẹœpṫ€0F“kKgGṅcCjJ”iⱮUḌ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///o7kNbUx81rTk84@GunUcnFzzcuRrIM3B71DAn2zvd/eHO1mTnLK9HDXMzH21cF/pwR8//w@1ABZH//0dzKbmXJjtnKulwKWUngqB7PoidmOmd6JyZmV6ane@VChIAC4KI0uxsoFx6Zlaqc6J7YmJyvldmpnc2WCq9FGiTN1i/e@nhjYmJYOFYAA)

Jelly has built-in for... 1-byte `ṅ`.

**Explanation**

```
Żµ             Prepend 0 to the string.
  e€  œp       Split at...
    Øẹ           the vowels. (0 is not a vowel)

ṫ€0            For each sublist `l` takes `l[-1:]`.
                 If the initial list is empty the result is empty,
                 otherwise the result is a list contain the last element.
   F           Flatten. (concatenate the results)

“kKgGṅcCjJ”iⱮ  Find the index of each character in the list.
                 Get 0 if not found (i.e., for `0` or `ñ`)
UḌ             Upend (reverse) and then convert from decimal.
```

Comment: I didn't find a way to save bytes with that, but `O%47%10` gives a unique index in `[0...9]` for each consonant. (Which means that `O%47` with the implicit modulo of `ị` would allow to pick up the correct value in an array of 10 entries.)

Comment: @Arnauld [`6;µe€Øẹœpṫ€0O%47ị“ ʠḷ’Œ?’¤Ṛ`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/M@tDW1EdNaw7PeLhr59HJBQ93rgbyDPxVTcwf7u5@1DBH4dSChzu2P2qYeXSSPZA8tOThzln/D7cDFUX@/x/NpeRemuycqaTDpZSdCILu@SB2YqZ3onNmZnppdr5XKkgALAgiSrOzgXLpmVmpzonuiYnJ@V6Zmd7ZYKn00oc7W73B@t1LD29MTAQLxwIA) but also 27 unless it can be golfed.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 126 bytes

```javascript
_=>(l=_.match(/[kgñṅcj][aeiou]/gi))?l.map(a=>"ñkKgGṅcCjJ".indexOf(a[0])).reverse``.join``+(/[ aiueo]/.test(_[0])?0:''):0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bdDPboJAEAbwe59iw4XdmPJHTa0m4IEDiRxMejUEJjhsl0WWyK6pD9AH8tizT9InoZgetNXM9TffZL4KDtAVe9Hq50ZtsS@DPgtCWgeZswNdvFN3I/n59P31WVTpBlAok7pcMLasB9BSCELrfJIJjy8kqlaWI5otfqxLChsvZczZ4wH3Hea5UynR5PloiCQgDKrUdTR2mmYXuPQWts0WXl@oplM1OrXitKRWbIpIWIyMiE2CkMymNnv6RyRcJlZXNfV9/95BApEQ3Ei1wqud@5PZ2LvXFvklIfGI667fCO5afXRLqDs8EmV0a/SDG9fgB5lGSpEAFxVGEAMUaiVEIm92/PnLdPY6GfsPlrkZKk5uvhxP7lFszieAP5HeUFn/Aw)

Comment: you can save a few bytes by changing `x=[..."ñkKgGṅcCjJ"]` to just `x="ñkKgGṅcCjJ"` since `indexOf` works with Strings too

Comment: This doesn't seem to treat initial vowels as `0`, so fails the test cases 3 and 6 (as can be seen in the Output on TIO).

Comment: @sundar My bad, Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <strike>152</strike> 143 bytes

```
func[s][t:"ñkKgGṅcCjJ"c: charset t
d: copy{}parse s[opt[1 2 not c(alter d 0)]any[copy n c not c(insert
d(index? find/case t n)- 1)| skip]]d]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU@7bsMwDNz9FYSmeCjadPTSwYMAe8sqaCAk2WVUSIIeQIO0Yz8oY@d8Sb/ElYGiEDiQdzzegdHo7WS0kN0ybEtxSiQp8sDuNzuv/Of7S43niakB1CvGZDLkTlfgw@X6GXYGkvAhiyM8g/MZ1AHfsomg4amX6C5il4ID9bcll0ysHnXQ5v0FltofFVafDK5/gGP/AclSkFLLLURyGRZgvKiRWPePLe7FfUMhzTgSrcX6yTR8K2nmYm09WOlsRuSIyk9Es20Va6nfz20EL/cb1ly2/QI)

### Readable:

```
f: func[s] [
    t: "ñkKgGṅcCjJ"
    c: charset t
    d: copy {}
    parse s [
        opt [ 1 2 not c (alter d 0) ]
        any [ 
              copy n c not c (insert d (index? find/case t n) - 1)
            | skip 
        ]
    ]
    d
]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>48</s> <s>47</s> 45 bytes

```
'ng'98Ztt'y'whw11Y2m)'ykKgGbcCjJ'tfqXEt10<)oP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HUy7CgIxEOz9kcXOs1KwixJIGgsLtXI94rpZL0HIctzXx0SGgXkxE5ZPfVRIBPvdvRRYYH7Pw3DbTmtYxJN9jiY6KK/v9VSGzWGdz/V4qWB1NAwrEOywuUlkj4aZVLILzfeoUUVaQRyDQYs4ZsfspTcSyClFJR@oWdJEvh9ZTQvifxKbZJ8TBfgB)

*('b' instead of 'd' to save a byte)*
*(-2 bytes thanks to Luis Mendo)*

MATLAB (and hence MATL) treating strings as a dumb series of bytes made porting @TFeld's Python solution harder than I imagined (maybe a straight loop solution would have been easier here?). Ended up using the alternate `'ng'`, `'ny'` input method, and replacing `ng` with `b` at the beginning for easier processing.

Explanation:

```
        % Implicit input (assume 'junyiKonge')
 'ng'   % string literal
 98     % 'b'
 Zt     % replace substring with another (stack: 'junyiKobe')
 t      % duplicate that (stack: 'junyiKobe' 'junyiKobe')
 'y'    % string literal
 w      % swap elements in stack so 'y' goes before input (stack: 'junyiKobe' 'y' 'junyiKobe')
 h      % horizontal concatenation (prepend 'y' to input string) (stack: 'junyiKobe' 'yjunyiKobe')
 w      % swap stack (stack: 'yjunyiKobe' 'junyiKobe')
 11Y2   % place 'aeiou' in stack (stack: 'yjunyiKobe' 'junyiKobe' 'aeiou')
 m      % set places with a vowel to True i.e. 1 (stack: 'yjunyiKobe' 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1)
 )      % index into those places (stack: 'jyKd')
 'ykKgGdcCjJ' % string literal
 tfq    % generate numbers 0 to 9 (stack: 'jyKd' 'ykKgGdcCjJ' 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
 XE     % replace elements in first array which are found in second,
        %  with corresponding elements from third
 t10<)  % keep only elements that are less than 10 (removes extraneous vowels)
 o      % convert from string to double (numeric) array (stack: 8 0 2 5)
 P      % flip the order of elements (stack: 5 2 0 8)
        % (implicit) convert to string and display
```

Comment: Thanks, done. Do you know if MATLAB/Octave has anything to index into/iterate through a string across Unicode codepoints instead of bytes? Doesn't look like it, their Unicode support seems atrociously bad in general, but maybe I missed something.

Comment: Also, the MATL manual mentions " if input is a string or character array" in a couple of places - are those two different things? Anything to do with the fancy new [double-quoted strings](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/characters-and-strings.html) in MATLAB?

Comment: Matlab has `unicode2native`, but I think that's now what you want. I agree, Unicode support in MATLAB is not the best. And don't get me started with Octave :-D As for MATL, it was designed before the new string data type existed in MATLAB (and I don't like it much anyway), so in MATL a "string" is the same as it used to be in old MATLAB versions: a row vector of chars. I've made a note to clarify that in the documentation, thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 27 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
âΔxñW⌡╪c§âaQ&δ▓äHê╠$╞╣;→◄vΓ
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=83ff78a457f5d8631583615126ebb2844888cc24c6b93b1a1176e2&i=GucCi%0AkakakaGo%0AaiKaCiigukoJe%0A%0Aa%0AukkiKagijeCaGaacoJiiKka%0Agu%E1%B9%85Ko%0AGu%C3%B1aaka%0A%E1%B9%85u%E1%B9%85u&a=1&m=2)